# How to create JSON file in assets dynamically using java code OR update existing json file using java code in android

Tags: java, android, json, assets

**how to update JSON file in assets folder or how to create a new JSON file in assets dynamically using java code.**

I want to update my JSON file dynamically from web data

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.com!  Please review submission guidelines in stackoverflow.com/help.  Please provide an example of your code so far, and some other information to help someone provide useful input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to update JSON file in assets folder or how to create a new JSON file in assets dynamically using java code.

You can't. Assets are read-only.

> I want to update my JSON file dynamically from web data

You would need to store that JSON in an ordinary file (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`). Then, either:

- Copy the asset to that file on first run of your app, overwriting the file as needed from the Web. That way, you always can turn to that file to get the JSON data that you need.
- Use the asset as a fallback. If you look for the JSON file, and it does not exist, that means you have not downloaded updated data, so you read the JSON out of the asset. If the JSON file *does* exist, though, it is newer than the asset, so you read the JSON out of the file.